# After updating to Play 2.2 I get "Memory quota exceeded" errors on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

As stated I get R14 errors on Heroku recently. This happens even setting max heap to e.g. 300M.

FYI: On my local machine the process never exceedes 400M, the heap is - even under load testing - never bigger then 250M. I use Scalate as templating engine.

Any ideas why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: It might be other stuff than the heap, the heroku memory limit is heap + all other kind of memory, thread stacks etc. Very hard to debug though. Have seen some people parsing some proc-file to try to see what is using memory outside of the JVM but had little success with it myself.

Comment: We are having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: hey. not really. i do use the 2x dyno with 1G mem for the productive system, which is a workaround, but works and was also recommended by heroku. for our test systems i just ignore the errors. the "mem quota exceeded" is just a warning and has no real impact and the memory usage is stable at 100% on our systems. so this is not an issue any more.

Comment: I think since play 2.2, it doesn't pick up the memory config from Heroku and the jvms just takes the ram it gets. That's just guess and I haven't figured out yet how to set that.

Answer (score 0):

play 2.2.0 had an issue with the case sensitivity of JAVA_OPTS, that's why your memory configuration wasn't honored. see this thread https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1928

it was fixed in play 2.2.2, so I guess this is no longer an issue